# How to install a second/third/python on my system?

Tags: python, packaging, software-distribution, software-packaging

How can I install (on Linux) a plain Python distribution to e.g. `/opt/myPythonProject/python`? When I afterwards install packages (e.g. `pip`) all packages should go in `/opt/myPythonProject`. It should simply ignore system python and it's packages.

My ultimate goal is to place my own code in `/opt/myPythonProject/mycode`, then zip op the entire project root directory, to deploy it on customer machine. Does this in general work (assuming my own arch/OS/etc. is the same).

So the bigger question is: can I deliver python/packages/my own code in 1 big zip? If yes, what do I need to take into account?

If not: what is the easiest solution to distribute a Python application together with the runtimes/packages and to get this deployed as **application user (non root)**.

Comment: Isn't that what virtualenv (https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)  is for?

Answer (score 3):

Use python virtual environment. Follow the below commands.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <my-new-directory>
source <my-new-directory>/bin/activate
pip install <my-package-name>
```

By doing so all your packages gets installed in the folder:

```
<my-new-directory>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: Chetan is right.  In addition, you should consider installing Virtualenvwrapper which makes it a little easier to use.  https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org

Comment: You don't need virtualenvwrapper, put your shebang line as `#!/path/to/venv/bin/python` and you'll be golden

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue recently with how to distribute my Python program as a stand alone. I used Pyinstaller (http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

You can include other data files such as exes or images by adding their paths to the generated spec file. The documentation is pretty good at explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

I use

- virtualenv for multiple Python installations
- setuptools for packaging (via pip)